# Can I set a video as boot animation using Plymouth in Arch Linux?

Tags: archlinux, boot-animation

I'm new to Arch and I need your help. I like a video(Watch Dogs loading screen animation) and I want to set it as my Arch's boot animation. Is there a way I could do it?? I'm using Plymouth. I would like to know your answers. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-read the wiki article [plymouth](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Plymouth) and follow the section on adding custom themes, the watchdogs intro theme can be found [here](https://github.com/1BB3/watch-dogs-boot-animation-ubuntu)

Note: this will make your computer play the whole animation, even if the boot itself is faster than that. there is no way around that for now